# tabs incorrectly refreshing on page return

Tags: php, css, tabs, return

The two pages I'm going to be talking about are [VelocityMicro.com/Cruz.php](http://www.velocitymicro.com/cruz.php) and [VelocityMicro.com/PC.php](http://www.velocitymicro.com/pc.php) (I'm viewing them in Firefox)

My issue is that on Cruz.php, when you click on one of the later tabs ("R100 Series" for example), click on an accessory (let's say "8GB SD Card") -- the page will link to where I want it too... and when you hit the back button, it takes you back to the last-opened "R100 Series" tab.  That's fine.  It's supposed to be like that.

On PC.php though, it will bring you back to the first tab, "Gaming", instead of what your last tab viewed.  I need it to go back to the last viewed tab; identical to how Cruz.php does.
So let's say you go on PC.php, select the "Servers" tab.  Select a server.  It links to the server page.  But you want to hit the "back" button and have the "Servers" tab still be active....

Does anyone have any insight as to why PC.php would behaving differently?

They are referencing identical js files and their css style files may be different, but are honestly identical (copy&pasted matches except for different div heights, number of tabs, other superficial height/width things)

Comment: I should probably also add that PC.php has SAP Inventory Management Software on it and Cruz.php doesn't.  Not sure if that might be the cause since SAP is server-side, but still....

Comment: More than likely, this is a JS/AJAX thing

Comment: You will not be able to control that functionality if the user uses the back button. Consider adding your own back button with custom javascript that maintains the active state of the tab last viewed.

Comment: @anuragbh interesting.  but if i can't control the fact that the back button will go to the last active tab, how is okay on Cruz.php?  I just can't find any difference on the pages' coding that would make one behave and one not?

Comment: I'm stumped :(. It doesn't behave like that for me in Chrome though.

Comment: Yeah, chrome doesn't really like our site.  The drop down menu doesn't work on /cruz.php , /pc.php , or /velocityhpc.php in chrome either.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own 'Back' button on each page, that navigates the user back to the last active tab. This is probably your best bet as it will give you full control over the functionality and uniformity in its implementation across all browsers.